# MATLAB: Create movie from cell array of uint8 images

Tags: image, matlab, video, image-processing, movie

I have 20 grayscale images of type `uint8` stored in a 1x20 cell array named `flow8`. I want to generate a movie from them. My current approach is:

```
% Generate images.
for i = 1:20
    flow8{i} = round(rand(100, 100)*255+1);
end

% Get into 4-D shape.
n = size(flow8,2);
matSize = size(flow8,1);
imageStack = reshape(cell2mat(flow8),matSize,[],n);
imageStack = permute(imageStack, [1 2 4 3]);

% Create movie.
mov = immovie(imageStack, gray)
implay(mov)
```

Here, I have added an image generation loop to make the code compilable.

With this code, the generated movie consists of only one horizontal line.

What do I need to do to get a proper movie? Or is there a better way to make a movie from my images?

I am using MATLAB R2015b academic on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely at your code, `flow8` is `1 x 20`. When you do your reshaping, you compute `matSize` with:

```
matSize = size(flow8, 1)
```

Well, that value is `1`, because as we said the shape of the cell array is `1 x 20`.

Instead, you likely wanted the size of *each image*. In which case, you'll want to index into the cell array to get the value and then take the size of *that*.

```
matSize = size(flow8{1});
```

Potentially another (much shorter) way to do this though, it so use `cat` to concatenate along the 4th dimension. Then you avoid all of the `reshape` and `permute` manipulations.

```
imageStack = cat(4, flow8{:});
```

Comment: Dammit... stop beating me to the punch! +1.

Comment: I actually changed that line to `matSize = size(flow8{1},1);` and that did the trick. Thank you so much, @Suever!